# print newline in process substitution

Tags: bash

This is in bash(5.0.3(1)-release) / ubuntu 19

When I ran :

```
printf "%s" $'\n'
```

It printed out a new line.

Now when I run:

```
result="$(printf "%s" $'\n')"
printf "<%s>" "$result"
```

I expect $result contains a newline, but it's empty.

Can someone explain ?

Comment: Try it like this `result="$(printf "1%s" $'\n2')"; printf "<%s>" "$result"`

Comment: I know we can do that, I just want an explanation of what happens in my post.

Answer (score 2):

From [posix shell manual, from chapter about process substitution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03), emphasis mine:

> The shell shall expand the command substitution by executing command in a subshell environment (see Shell Execution Environment) and replacing the command substitution (the text of command plus the enclosing "$()" or backquotes) with the standard output of the command, **removing sequences of one or more `<newline>`s at the end of the substitution**.

It's impossible to store trailing newlines with process substitution. You can use for example `printf -v` bash extension:

```
printf -v result "%s" $'\n'
```

For most portability, I go with encoding the string in hex using `od` or `xxd` and store the string in hex. Or just store the resulting string in a file.